# Сирник VS чизкейк?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, стилістика

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA) читаємо:

> **чизкейк** — страва європейської та американської кухні, що представляє собою сирний десерт від сирної запіканки до тістечка суфле.
>
> **сирник** - корж із сиром і приправами.

***То чи можна ці слова замінювати одне одним, якщо мова йде про сирний десерт?*** Наприклад, найпопулярнішим за західній Україні є “Львівський сирник” у різних його варіаціях, чи можна сказати “Львівський чизкейк”? Адже часто у закладах можна побачити окремо напис “сирник”, окремо - “чизкейк”.

P. S.: Так, у Вікіпедії чизкейк пишуть через і, однак розумію, що це помилка, адже згідно із правилом дев’ятки пишемо це слово через и.

Comment: Поназапозичують тих слів Якщо страва справді кардинально відрізняється від сирників, які печуть в нас, то можна називати це простіше - сирний торт, сирне тістечко, сирне суфле, сирна запіканка.  Слова чіз та кейк явно не вписуються в нашу мову.

Comment: Повністю з Вами погоджуюсь 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оскільки, слово **чизкейк** має досить широкий спектр значень, тому, на хвилі запозичень,  ввійшло в українську мову. Очевидно, що слово запозичили, але не повністю зрозуміли до яких видів сирних виробів його вживати, що часто бачимо у меню ресторанів.

У [Вікіпедії](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) знаходимо, що **сирник=чизкейк**:

> **Сирник** — (від слова сир) - це власне українська назва улюбленого світового десерту під назвою чизкейк (від англ. Cheesecake).

Однак, якщо йде мова про *«Львівський **сирник**»*, то не варто замінювати слово на **чизкейк**.
Підтвердження знаходимо у [Міні-курсі «Все про чизкейк та сирники»](HTTPS://LIST.IN.UA/%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2/AFISHA/43180-%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%20%22%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D0%A7%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%22), який проводиться у Львові:

> Програма курсу:
>
> 1. Брауні чіз з малиною
> 2. Чіз Нью Йорк
> 3. Чіз Кейк Орео
> 4. Лимонно- чорничний Чіз Кейк
> 5. Львівський **сирник**

У статті [Легендарний Львівський Сирник](http://culinar-academy.com/legendarnij-l-vivs-kij-sirnik/) також знаходимо, що **сирник≠чизкейк.**
А мегавідоме кафе [«Львівські пляцки»](http://www.pliacky.lviv.ua/uk/delivery/) , яке спеціалізується і на виготовленні «Львівського **сирника**» у меню не має **чизкейків** взагалі.

Отже, слово **сирник** часто замінюється на **чизкейк**. У меню нерідко знаходимо розмежування між ними, яку можна пояснити складом випічки. Печений з родзинками, сир викладений на тісто- **сирник,** непечений з різними фруктами(холодний) - **чизкейк**, хоча часто і склад не стає головним для розмежування(нечітке). Однак, цілком зрозуміло, що львівський **сирник»≠чизкейк**